# C++ преобразование string к LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, строки

Есть следующий код, который преобразовывает string в LPCTSTR:

```
LPCTSTR stringToLPCTSTR(string helpMe)
{
    wstring path_wstr(helpMe.begin(), helpMe.end());
    return path_wstr.c_str();
}
```

wcout ничего не выводил. Отладка показала, что в helpMe содержится необходимая строка, а в переменной path_wstr "Ошибка чтения строки". Я пробовал другой вариант преобразования:

```
LPCTSTR stringToLPCTSTR(string helpMe)
{
    CA2T wt (helpMe.c_str());
    return wt;
}
```

Переменная wt, при отладке, показала, что содержит нужную строку, но функция возвращает пустые квадраты.

Посоветуйте, что тут можно сделать или есть ли другой способ преобразования.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` может быть алиасом либо для `char const *` в текущей кодировке либо `wсhar_t const *`. Соответственно вам при необходимости надо сделать новую строку, осуществив преобразование кодировки и вызвать метод [::std::basic_string::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Единственное решение которое я нашел - это в настройках конфигурации убрать набор символов Unicode.

Comment: Ну да, примерно как отрубить ногу, если ботинки жмут...

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя возвращать что-то локальное из функции...

```
LPCTSTR stringToLPCTSTR(string helpMe)
{
    wstring path_wstr(helpMe.begin(), helpMe.end());
    return path_wstr.c_str();
}
```

После возврата указателя строка `path_wstr` будет уничтожена, и куда указывает этот указатель — неизвестно.

Просто получайте широкую строку, как вы это делаете в функции, и используйте ее `c_str()`, там, где вам нужен `LPCTSTR` (если, конечно, у вас действительно Unicode).

Чтобы вернуть указатель — надо динамически выделять память, которую потом надо не забыть удалить. Или, как вариант, использовать

```
static wstring path_wstr;
```

Только каждый новый вызов такой функции будет делать невалидным старое возвращенное значение.

Comment: Я нашел эти функции в интернете и лишь немного подредачил их, а про const char*, я пытался преобразовывать вот так:
```
LPCTSTR helpMe = (LPCTSTR)allDirs[i].c_str();
```
Но результат все тот же

Comment: P.S Необходимо LPCTSTR а не LPCSTR, это немного разные вещи https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#lpcwstr

Comment: Суть от этого не меняется. Получайте `wstring`, и используйте ее `c_str()`. Чтобы указатель был корректным, надо, чтобы была жива память, на которую он указывает.